# Run multiple npm scripts at once

Tags: build, npm

I have a number of npm scripts that I would like to run in a sequence.

At the moment I am accomplishing this by:

```
npm run clean && npm run browserify && npm run test
```

I would like to just one npm command, is that possible?

```
npm run clean browserify test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a feature that npm as of v3 does not support

Comment: Update: npm v5.2.1 still does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a script command in your package.json like:

```
"scripts": {
 "clean": "clean ...",
 "browserify": "browserify ...",
 "test": "test ...",
 "all": "npm run clean && npm run browserify && npm run test"
}
```

You will be able to run all your script with:

```
 npm run all
```